# how do I console.log every time specific users tweets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I tried to use both `twitter` and `twit` npm packages but I can't figure out how to get most recent tweet from a specific user or trigger code then this specific user tweeted something.

EDIT:
I tried this

```
const twitter = require('twitter');
const client = new twitter({
  consumer_key: cfg.consumer_key,
  consumer_secret: cfg.consumer_secret,
  // bearer_token: cfg.bearer_token
  access_token_key: cfg.access_token_key,
  access_token_secret: cfg.access_token_secret
});

client.get('user/timeline ', (error, tweets, response) => {
  if (error) return console.log(error);
  console.log(tweets);
  // console.log(response);  // Raw response object.
});
```

but I got `[ { message: 'Sorry, that page does not exist', code: 34 } ]`

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail, perhaps code you've already tried?

Comment: @MattCoady edited

Comment: @guest271314 ops, deleted "s" be accident

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to the resource?

Comment: @guest271314 from where to I get full path?

Comment: Instead of `user/timeline`, use something that is supported: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/api-reference-index I'm testing your code with `statuses/user_timeline` and it works fine.

Comment: @pekaP Not sure what you mean. The full URL path to the *witter URL that is being requested.

Comment: @guest271314 The twitter api expects a special resource path, not a full twitter.com URL

Comment: @ChrisG got it, but how do I get someone's else tweets not mines?

Comment: okay got it nevermind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `twitter` npm module:

```
client.get('statuses/user_timeline', { user_id: 123456 }, (error, tweets, response) => {
  if (error) return console.log(error);
  console.log(tweets);
  // console.log(response);  // Raw response object.
});
```